# Does .Net Core 3.1 have an event driven method of detecting GPIO pin changes?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, gpio, .net-core-3.1, orange-pi

I'm creating a .Net Core 3.1 console app to read to and write from GPIO pins on an Orange Pi Zero (similar to a Raspberry Pi Zero). It is running Armbian Focal (Ubuntu). I'm using .Net Core's System.Device.Gpio library.

I have managed to get the reading to and writing from the GPIO pins working - no problem. But the way I am reading the pins is by doing a gpioController.Read() inside a loop. I was wondering if System.Device.Gpio has an event driven method of reading a GPIO pin? In other words, if a pin goes from high to low, or low to high, that an event - let's call it "gpioPinStateChanged" - is triggered. Is there such a thing?

I know I could create my own even notification system, but I was wondering if .Net Core perhaps had something built in? I've looked at a dozen code samples, and none of them have anything like that, so I'm guessing there isn't...

Thanks

Comment: First of all, you probably meant .Net Core IoT libraries. Second, you have to be sure that you are using `libgpiod` backend. Third, read their code, they are OSS! https://github.com/dotnet/iot

Comment: Thanks for the reply 0andriy. Yes, I believe System.Device.Gpio (and System.Device.Bindings) are part of the .Net Core IoT libraries, you are correct. I did look at the link you sent me, yesterday, and I didn't see anything regarding an event-driven method of detecting pin state changes on the GPIO, but I will go through the documentation in more detail now. I might have missed something. I will also look into libgpiod. Thanks again.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/master/src/System.Device.Gpio/System/Device/Gpio/LibgpiodDriverEventHandler.cs shows clearly that there is a support.

Comment: Aha, that seems like what I was looking for. Thanks 0andriy - I guess I didn't look properly. Will study the code now. Much appreciated!

Comment: For an exchange, could you point me out to the documentation how to build this library and what are the prerequisites?

Comment: @0andriy I actually found this site which I used to help me: http://blog.timwheeler.io/building-a-pwm-fan-controller-with-dotnet-iot/

Answer (score 1):

Following 0andriy's comments, I saw that you can indeed register events to detect GPIO pin state changes. Thanks to his post, I also found another great post of someone doing the same. He uses GPIO pin change events to calculate the RPM of a fan.
http://blog.timwheeler.io/building-a-pwm-fan-controller-with-dotnet-iot/

Comment: The link seems to be dead, it could be great if you elaborate your answer here with an example of code that allowed you to achieve the event trigger on GPIO change